# Parsing JavaScript Output Using Selenium and Beautifulsoup

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, beautifulsoup

Have extracted the JavaScript data using Selenium and can see the data I require ("meeting_summary_reference") is contained in a dictionary type 'structure'. Python json does not parse this type of data and test2_text and test33 are both blank. So tag does not convert to text. Beautiful soup strings do not work for me either. Not proficient at complex Regex.
At a loss of what to try next.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/A38/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')

driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.maximize_window()
# Navigate to the application home page
driver.get("https://www.sportinglife.com/racing/results/2020-11-23")

innerHTML = driver.execute_script("return document.body.innerHTML")
print("\nJS PAGE SOURCE:", "\n", driver.page_source)

j_str = driver.page_source
html = j_str
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print("\nBSOBJ:", "\n", bsObj.prettify())

test2 = bsObj.find('script', attrs={'id': '__NEXT_DATA__'})
print("\nTEST2: \n", test2)
print("\nTYPE TEST2: \n", type(test2))
print("\nLENGTH TEST2: \n", len(test2))
test2_text = bsObj.find('script', attrs={'id': '__NEXT_DATA__'}).getText()
print("\nTEST2_TEXT: \n",test2_text)

test33 = test2.find(text = "meeting_summary_reference")
print("\nTEST33: \n", test33)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure you can extract that information with `beautifulsoup`, but you can use this regex:

```
import re
...
test2_text = bsObj.find('script', attrs={'id': '__NEXT_DATA__'}) # I edited this line also
pattern = r'\"meeting_summary_reference\":\{(.*?)(\{.*\})?\},'
test33 = re.findall(pattern, str(test2_text), re.M)
```

Which will find all nested objects named `meeting_summary_reference` and then you can convert it to python dictionary and extract desired information.

Comment: Thank you.
That has worked so far, as it outputs a list "[('"id":80562,"external_reference":[]', ''), ('"id":80562,"external_reference":[]', ''), ('"id": ....."]

What is the best way to obtain the rest of the contained information such as

"race_summary_reference"
"name"
"course_name"
"course_surface" etc

so that the data is kept together in the correct group?


test2.text Output Snippet:

[{"meeting_summary_reference":{"id":80562,
 "external_reference":[]},"race_summary_reference":{"id":599007,"external_reference":[]},
 "name":"EBF Stallions 'National Hunt' Novices' ......"

Comment: you can replace regex pattern `r'\"[Put here other names]\":\{(.*?)(\{.*\})?\},'`. Just replace `meeting_summary_reference` with other names.